# Bootstrap Modal External Content opens outside of modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open a remote web application in a Bootstrap modal using the following:

```
<a href="http://localhost/PECIMS/DocumentManagement.aspx" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remoteModal" class="btn btn-default">Open Modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="remoteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="remoteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The app opens but NOT in a modal window, and when I close it, it closes both itself and the application that called it.  I am using asp.net MVC.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the remote site to open in the Bootstrap modal, I had to place it in an iFrame like so:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Document Management</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <iframe height="660" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="{{iframe}}"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Exit</button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
        </div>
```

The src is the url of the remote site.  I hope this helps someone else.  Happy coding!